# css drop down menu is only showing last list item

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, listitem

My drop down menu is only showing the last drop down items. I know my css has something wrong with it, but I cannot figure it out. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="menuBar">
    <nav class="Menu"> 
    <ul class="main">
    <li><a href="http://www.lombardisonthebay.com/" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="wedding.html">Weddings</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="wedding-gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="restaurant.html">Restaurant</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="restaurant-gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="social.html">Special Occasions</a></li>
    <li><a href="corporate.html">Corporate</a></li>
    <li><a href="upcoming.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="locations.html">Our Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
nav.Menu {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 14px;
}

nav.Menu .main li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav.Menu .main li ul li {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

nav.Menu .main li ul li { 
    background: #83562c; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -2px;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}

nav.Menu .main li:hover ul li { 
    background: #83562c; 
}

nav.Menu .main li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index:99;
}

nav.Menu a {
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 13px/42px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav.Menu a:hover    { 
    color: #eacc90;
}
```

Comment: Your sub menu list items are positioned absolutely so they are all stacked on top of each other. Here is a fiddle of your current code http://jsfiddle.net/7zLbq0b2/

Comment: When I make them relative the main menu disappears.

Comment: Please help me with this mess I made.

Answer (score 0):

Huangism is right, your use of `position:absolute` is breaking the dropdown. I've rewritten your CSS in the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nklein/vx91sy8v/6/), but it's still hackish.

I'd recommend doing some reading on dropdown menus:

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu

Comment: Thanks! I believe those articles are how I got into this mess in the first place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

drove me to desparation but with a little trickery position:absolute does work     http://jsfiddle.net/z509cjmg/3/. Adapted from here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/multi-level-dropdown-menu

```
.navmenu ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  margin-left: 142px;
  margin-top: -30px;

}
```